# What are the conditions for 2-dimensional curve fitting when the estimator function is a type of sine and cosine?

Tags: least-squares, cosine-similarity

What are the conditions for 2-dimensional curve fitting when the estimator function is a type of sine and cosine?
For example I wanted to estimate F=x*y with A*sin (((n*pi)/L)*x)*sin ((((n*pi)/L)*z) function (A is amplitude). I used least square method with following procedure:

[image]

Using orthogonal property of sine function:

[image]

When testing the results the error for most test points is too large. 
Thank you

Comment: unclear at all what you're modeling

Comment: I want to fit sin(wx)sin(wz) to a function contains sqrt(x^2+y^2) and 1/(sqrt(x^2+y^2) and combination of them.

Comment: what is the significance of $xy$?

Comment: the function also contains xy. but even for this simple function (xy) the fitting dose not give a good result.

Comment: $xy$ is a monotonic function on both arguments, why would a periodic function such as sine give a good fit?

Comment: According to Fourier method by adding different frequencies of sin() functions, it is possible to estimate other functions. Is there any especial condition for Fourier series? As I know Fourier series can be extracted from least square method using orthogonal property of sin() function.